# Migrating from the Docker runtime to the Containerd runtime on a specific NODE kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to know if it's possible to change the param --image-type COS_CONTAINERD in the google cloud command line but on a specific node.

I found this command below :
gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --image-type COS_CONTAINERD [--node-pool POOL_NAME]

But it will update my entire node pool so it'will create a disturbance on my services web .
Every node in my pool will be updated in the same time ( destroy & re-create ).

Or there is another way  ???

I would like to know if you have the same topic / issue . It' will help me during this migration.

Thanks for your experience .

Answer (score 1):

The command you are mentioning, will update all the nodes within the node pool.

I would suggest you trying to create a new node pool on your cluster and choose the COS_CONTAINERD image type, and once you have the new node pool with `cos-containerd` migrate your workload to the new node pool node(s) by following this [process](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool#step_4_migrate_the_workloads). This will also help you to manage the downtime.